# Assigning functions as class attributes (Python)

Tags: python, oop, attributes

How is it possible to store a function as a class attribute when added via an object of the class using initial OOP system Python?

Note that it isn't known how many functions will be added.

```
def make_class(attrs, base=None):
    """Return a new class (a dispatch dictionary) with given class attributes"""

    # Getter: class attribute (looks in this class, then base)
    def get(name):
        if name in attrs: return attrs[name]
        elif base:        return base['get'](name)

    # Setter: class attribute (always sets in this class)
    def set(name, value): attrs[name] = value

    # Return a new initialized object instance (a dispatch dictionary)
    def new(*args):
        # instance attributes (hides encapsulating function's attrs)
        attrs = {}

        # Getter: instance attribute (looks in object, then class (binds self if callable))
        def get(name):
            if name in attrs:       return attrs[name]
            else:
                value = cls['get'](name)
                if callable(value): return lambda *args: value(obj, *args)
                else:               return value

        # Setter: instance attribute (always sets in object)
        def set(name, value):       attrs[name] = value

        # instance dictionary
        obj = { 'get': get, 'set': set }

        # calls constructor if present
        init = get('__init__')
        if init: init(*args)

        return obj

    # class dictionary
    cls = { 'get': get, 'set': set, 'new': new }
    return cls
```

Comment: What problem does this code solve?

Comment: Implementation of an alternative OOP system using dictionaries.

Comment: So your target is to build OOP with python. Then you should mention it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a `class`-keyword or for dynamic class creation the `type`-function. Instead of inventing something yourself you can use:

```
cls = type('Name', (base_class, ), {'attr1': 123, 'attr2': some_function})
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
class Foo(object): pass

def some_function(self):
    print 'in some_function'

setattr(Foo, 'some_function', some_function)

foo = Foo()
foo.some_function()  # --> in some_function
```